# Converter not hooked to PropertyChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, converters

I have this treeview with an hierarchy binded to an entity framework model.
The rectangle below works only for the initial load. And does not update its color etc for when I fire the Propertychanged event.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding tblLines}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
        <Image Height="15" Margin="4" x:Name="imgTreeProject" Source="/DES STUDIO PR;component/Resources/Images/folder_closed.png"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin ="8" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Rectangle Name="X" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource CheckoutConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource CheckoutPersonConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource CheckoutToolTipVis},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Here are my converters:

```
public class CheckoutConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is TblBase)
        {
            var Baseentity = value as TblBase;

            if (Baseentity.COID == MainWindow.LocalUser.ID)
            {
                return Brushes.Green;
            }
            else if ((Baseentity.COID == 0) || (Baseentity.COID == null))
            {
                return Brushes.Transparent;
            }
            else if (Baseentity.COID != 0)
            {
                return Brushes.Black;
            }
        }
        return Brushes.Black;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CheckoutPersonConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is TblBase)
        {
            var Baseentity = value as TblBase;
            //COID equals other user's ID

            if ((Baseentity.COID != 0) && (Baseentity.COID != null) && (Baseentity.COID != MainWindow.LocalUser.ID))
            {
               var user = DESDatabase.GetUser(Baseentity.COID.Value);
               return "Checked out by " + user;
            }
            else if (Baseentity.COID == MainWindow.LocalUser.ID)
                return "You have this node checked out.";
            else
                return "error";
        }
        return "error";
    }

    public  object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CheckoutToolTipVis : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is TblBase)
        {
            var Baseentity = value as TblBase;
            //COID equals other user's ID

            if ((Baseentity.COID != 0) && (Baseentity.COID != null))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And my property changed event does get called here:

```
private Nullable<int> _coid;
public Nullable<int> COID
{
    get
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
        return _coid;
    }
    set
    {
        _coid = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The property changed events work for treeview bindings that do not use converters, therefore I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Why is the getter raising the notifypropertychanged event?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd because the values are loaded from a database. So they might have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

converters (IValueConverter) don't subscribe to PropertyChanged event, that's binding's responsibility.

currenlty the converter is used with binding to entire object, not to property:

```
Fill="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource CheckoutConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

so th updates of `COID` happen unnoticed.

you need to change bidning to

```
Fill="{Binding Path=COID,Converter={StaticResource CheckoutConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

and change converter as well:

```
public class CheckoutConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int?)
        {
            var COID = value as int?;

            if (COID == MainWindow.LocalUser.ID)
            {
                return Brushes.Green;
            }
            else if ((COID == 0) || (COID == null))
            {
                return Brushes.Transparent;
            }
            else if (COID != 0)
            {
                return Brushes.Black;
            }
        }
        return Brushes.Black;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an exception "runtime refused to evaluate expression at this time"

Comment: getter raising the notifypropertychanged event may be resposible for such error. `NotifyPropertyChanged();` in getter doesn't make sense, because someone is *already trying to get newest value*.